# Quand utiliser un point d'interrogation sur cette formulation ?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, ponctuation

Je rédigeais un mail et me posais cette question qui me reviens plutôt régulièrement. Devons-nous ponctuer :

> [...] Nous sommes toujours très intéressés et attendons votre retour.
> Nous aimerions savoir si tout se passe au mieux de votre côté dans
> l'étude de notre dossier ?

Ou

> [...] Nous sommes toujours très intéressés et attendons votre retour.
> Nous aimerions savoir si tout se passe au mieux de votre côté dans
> l'étude de notre dossier.

Vous pouvez répondre dans le cas plus général de la structure grammaticale de la phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pas de point d'interrogation puisque la phrase est une déclaration, pas une question :

> **Nous aimerions savoir** si tout se passe au mieux de votre côté dans l'étude de notre dossier.

Pour qu'un point d'interrogation soit requis, il aurait fallu écrire :

> **Est-ce que** tout se passe au mieux de votre côté dans l'étude de notre dossier **?**

Comment: Merci ! J’emploierai la deuxième formulation, bien meilleure :)

Answer (score 2):

Pas besoin de point d’interrogation quand c’est une interrogation indirecte.